Is there any performance improvement if I declare this const inside or outside the function?
Since this is an high-called function, is there any difference if I declare const QUERY inside or outside the fn insert()?
impl Player {
    pub async fn insert(
        db: sqlx::PgConnection,
        input: &InputPlayer,
    ) -> Result<Self> {
        const QUERY: &str = r#"INSERT INTO "player" ("team_id", "id", "other_fields") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)"#;

        let result = sqlx::query_as::<_, Self>(QUERY)
            .bind(input.team_id())
            .bind(input.id())
            .bind(input.other())
            .bind(input.other())
            .bind(input.other())
            .bind(input.other())
            .fetch_one(db)
            .await?;

        Ok(result)
    }
}


I suggest trying it both ways and measuring the time spent. My guess would be that the amount of time that could be spent assigning a string value will be insignificant compared to the amount of time spent executing the SQL query.

Let's have a look at the documentation:

To put it simply, constants are inlined wherever they’re used, making using them identical to simply replacing the name of the const with its value.

You can confirm this behavior with a simple assembly test. Let's have a look at the following code:
#[no_mangle]
pub fn x() -> &'static str {
    const A: &str = "Hello";
    A
}

const B: &str = "World";
#[no_mangle]
pub fn Y() -> &'static str {
    B
}

This compiles to the following amd64 assembly:
x:
        lea     rax, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        mov     edx, 5
        ret

Y:
        lea     rax, [rip + .L__unnamed_2]
        mov     edx, 5
        ret

.L__unnamed_1:
        .ascii  "Hello"

.L__unnamed_2:
        .ascii  "World"

As you can see, both strings end up being in the same location — stored statically as data in the resulting binary.
So, a short answer is, no, there is no performance difference, since in both cases it will be a static string living somewhere in the data section of the binary.

Furthermore, as documented in the Rust Reference under Item declarations: "Declaring an item within a statement block restricts its scope ... It is otherwise identical in meaning to declaring the item inside a module".

It will be evaluated at compile-time, regardless of whether you declare it inside or outside the function. So there shouldn't be any performance difference.
